# Given a file, how do I get thet targets which depends on that file?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I am using cmake to generate Makefiles.

Given a Cpp file, I want to know if it is possible to get the list of targets in a Makefile (or a CMakeLists.txt file) which depends on that file, directly or indirectly. Is it possible and if so, how ?

Comment: CMake does this analysis for you to determine the order to build when you run `make`.  Do you need this list for some other reason, or is it OK that CMake does this automatically behind the scenes?

Comment: You could `touch` the source file (`foo.cpp`), then `make -nd | grep Must`, and maybe a little `sed` to reduce the result to a simple list.

Comment: @SethMMorton The reason behind is that I want to see if I can launch compilation for that file and see the compilation errors output from my editor (emacs). I want to make a mode behaving mike fly-make. In complicated project, one file can be involved in multiple targets.

Comment: Inspired from @Beta's idea, if you want to see all of the dependencies of a target, regardless if any of those targets need to be remade: `make -nd targetOfInterest | grep -i considering | grep -Po "(?<=\`).*(?=')"`